# TYPO3 template library

Tags: templates, typo3

I'm looking for TYPO3 template libraries. They don't need to be free. I'm looking for real Typo3 templates, ready to import into a vanilla Typo3 installation, not just HTML or even PSD templates.

The reason I'm asking is that we have a number of customers with very tight budget. We'd like to give them a number of templates to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *were* such projects, but I assume that most of them are just finished now. TYPO3 has no default data/content structure and therefore it's hard to build useful sets as every implementation can be very individual.

For your own low-budget production I'd suggest to create some very typical *raw* implementations with sample data and some kind of preconfigured extensions ie.

- CMS+ News + contact form + gallery,
- CMS + News + FAQ...
- etc...

Then you can also prepare common `TypoScript` element for each scenario and finally just use any HTML template and map your prepared TS with minimal modifications.

Using `TemplaVoila` you don't need to change any single char in the HTML templates and it takes no more than 2 morning coffees (when mapping a simple template).

Answer (score 0):

A simple Typo3 template isn't really difficult to make but I think you mean a better browser compatibility support. Personally I've good experience with YAML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything like that out there, but is it just for content sites, or are you looking for sites with more functionality?

Any template can be adapted to TYPO3, you can see here http://webdevelopers.thedemo.ca/ where in the space of about an hour we grabbed a template from http://www.oswd.org/ and turned it into a TYPO3 site.  It's rough and messy, but shows the idea.